# SQL Syntax Formatting Tool

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I find the need to send SQL statements by email often and I was wondering if anyone had a tool that would color code the Oracle Reserved Words, Keywords, and Namespaces so that when the code is copied from the tool into say Lotus notes it would appear in the email as it does in the tool.

Comment: I don't have a problem copy/paste SSMS colour coded SQL into a Notes email, but what are you using - PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: I also found that I could copy from TOAD paste into MS Word and copy from MS Word into Notes and the formatting would look in notes as it did in TOAD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

[Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm?ref=g_wangz)
[image]

you must select the option

Output -> SQL (HTML:font)

Bye

Answer (score 2):

[SQLinForm](http://www.sqlinform.com/) - No download necessary. It uses a Java applet. Feature rich. That’s the one I like.

Comment: The online version has a 100 lines limit.

Comment: That's true but it shouldn't be a problem for SQL statements sent by email. I doubt (I hope so) the OP send statements bigger than 100 lines so often.

Comment: Yea, the 100 line limit is good to know but not an issue for email

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.ca) , encrypt it and send the pastebin link.